# QT Combo Box of Line Pattern

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

i want to make a line pattern combo box in Qt same as it is shown in the picture , 
please tell me is it possible to make a combo box in Qt like shown in the picture.
Any help would be appreciated

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way:

```
comboBox->setIconSize(QSize(100, 24));
comboBox->addItem(lineIcon, "");
comboBox->addItem(dotLineIcon, "");
comboBox->addItem(dashLineIcon, "");
...
```

Correct way:

```
comboBox->setItemDelegate(...);
```

Comment: i have used the easy way and generated icon with pixmp 
 now combobox is showing the line pattern but the problem is that it generate icon with a constant width , 
i want to to increase the size of icon but no success

Comment: The only way, that comes to my mind, is to inherit `QComboBox` and override `resizeEvent`.

Comment: Or install event filter.